# Creating applicationContext bean in java based spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, applicationcontext

I'm trying to build from scratch spring-based application using Java configurations, but I'm getting warning which I completely don't understand...
Can someone tell me what is wrong there?

Error:
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling     refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationContext': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext]: Specified class is an interface

Aplication initializer:

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer  implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
}
}
```

Application context configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("pl.wybornie.entity.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wyborniedb");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root123");

    return dataSource;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

    //sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("pl.wybornie.entity", "pl.wybornie.entity.cookBook");

    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new   HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
  }
```

These are only 2 configuration classes for whole project.

Whole code can be found at:
https://github.com/annweg/wybornie.pl/tree/new_build/project_workspace/wybornie

I'm quite newbie with spring and maybe there is some configuration missing there... I'm using Spring 4.1.6, Tomcat 7 and Java 7.

edit:
I have tried to register both ApplicationContext from Spring and my own configuration class - ApplicationContextConfig - the error is the same.
I've deleted Tomcat server and created new one, reopened Eclipse and still the same.
Either importing project as new (deleting all settings and .project file) didn't help, so maybe the error is somewhere in configuration...?

Comment: `ApplicationContext` and `ApplicationContextConfig` are two different types. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: when changing this ApplicationContextConfig to ApplicationContext it shows the same error message... And for me it has no sens, because whole configuration is in these ApplicationContextConfig...

Comment: No...change `ApplicationContext` (**a type that belongs to Spring**) to `ApplicationContextConfig` (**the type you've defined**) in the `onStartup` method.

Comment: Yes, I have like this at the beginning but error was still the same...
And I've clean Tomcat's directory as wel

Comment: No, the error is definitely not the same. Edit your question and add what you've changed and the exact error message.

Comment: I have the same error with both ApplicationContext and my class ApplicationContextConfig. I can even send you printscreens...
And deleting and creating new server still has the same behaviour.

Comment: I don't want you to send me print screens. I want you to show us the changes you made and the accompanying errors.

Comment: The problem now is with your project and Eclipse. The problem originally described is a typo, registering `ApplicationContext` instead of  your `ApplicationContextConfig`.

Comment: OK, but I have just:
a) Clean Tomcat Directory
b) uninstall Tomcat server with its all configurations and add it again.
c) Reopen Eclipse.
d) Delete project from eclipse, delete its settings and .project file and import it once again to Eclipse.
e) restart the Windows

Should I try another version of Tomcat or Java?
Maybe Java 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my Eclipse settings. I've delete all project content, change workspace and just copy/paste all classes and libs and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this type of error is often related to missing jars and/or classpath error. Check if you have some libraries not added to classpath, or the project is requiring some libs that are previously present but then removed. Sometimes I add jars to classpath and remove them and it works.